# How do I keep an App running in Background without rooting?

Tags: applications, ram, background-process

Mobile Legends in my phone(Xiaomi Redmi 5a) always restarts whenever I went to recent apps. And it is irritable when I'm in-game. What would normally cause this? How do I prevent it from happening?

P.S. I saw the post same with this and read the answer. But I don't want to root just for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same phone.

Go to Settings > Battery and Performance > Choose Apps > Click Mobile Legends > Set to No Restrictions.